# property of non-object error in xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

Hello I write following code to extract name and price from table with XPATH and curl.

```
   <?php
    include_once ("xpath.php");
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $ch = curl_init ("http://emalls.ir/%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA~Category~39~Search~Nokia");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //$page = curl_exec($ch);
    $page = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($page);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $data = array();


    // get all table rows and rows which are not headers
    $produstname = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td/a/text()');
    $produstprice = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td[8]/text()');
    $data = array();
    for ($x=0; $x<=1; $x++){
        $data[$x]['title'] = $produstname->item($x)->nodeValue;
        $data[$x]['price'] = $produstprice->item($x)->nodeValue;
    }
    ?>
```

These following two XPATH working on chrome to get name and price .

```
 name: $x("//table/tbody/tr/td/a/text()")
 price: $x("//table/tbody/tr/td[5]/text()")
```

but when use in following code give this error

```
 : Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Comment: *"in..."* in what?! The suspense is killing me

Comment: Could it be, just maybe, that there aren't 20 elements matching your XPath queries?

Comment: when I writed 1 elment give this error.

Comment: Biggest problem I can see is that there are no `<tbody>` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the site, I humbly suggest target the `id=""` attribute instead. You can also use foreach too. Example:

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://emalls.ir/%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA~Category~39~Search~Nokia");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$page = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//table[@id="grdprice"]/tr'); // target the row (the browser rendered <tbody>, but actually it really doesnt have one)

if($table_rows->length <= 0) { // exit if not found
    echo 'no table rows found';
    exit;
}

foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;
    if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'th') { // avoid headers
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'price' => trim($row->item(7)->nodeValue),
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xgGXLw)

Comment: Thank's.You're a professional PHP . why $data[] .. is Empty

Comment: @amirrasabeh thanks for the complement, but no, i haven't even scratched the surface of PHP, still a long ways to go

Comment: @amirrasabeh that is just simply stating that if you do not explicitly put an index on the assignment, it will append it on the end of the array

Comment: Do you have email. I want Always to  be in touch with you

Comment: @amirrasabeh no need to email me, if i can help you inside the scope of SO and seen your question, i'll try to answer if i know

Comment: Thank's @Ghost . what is trim in the trim($row->

Comment: @amirrasabeh that is just to remove extra whitespaces on the text, try to remove it and check what happens

Comment: I used your script top writed and manipulate (price' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),)  to get other table . this url http://wpu.ir/65pqe . But not support utf8. show character similar this "???? ????  ???? ??? ???"

Comment: @amirrasabeh try to add this one: `'name' => iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue)),` that will solve your issue

Comment: thank's. How remove tr tag with class in similar above script.